# Removing the White background from an image in illustrator cc

Tags: adobe-illustrator, background

trying the get rid of the white background so the background Ive made can be seen through the image - but its not letting me make a compound path to remove the white space or use the magic wand tool.

Any tips???

Comment: Welcome Sophie! Thanks for posting your question. Unfortunately, GD.SE is not designed to handle issues regarding basic software education.If you are seeking to learn how to accomplish something within an application, please review the application help files or try an internet search with your question or an internet search for a tutorial. Try googling: *Illustrator clipping mask*

Answer (score 0):

Create a mask to portion out the sections you want to be revealed. Trace the image using the pen tool, shape or outlined text. Remove any fill or stroke (This is not necessary but…) and stack over the image you wish to mask. Select both the shape and image and press `Cmd + 7` or `Object > Clipping Mask > Make`